# When I add a new servlet, all of my servelts can no longer be found

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

All I am doing is adding a new servlet to the web.xml like so:

```
<servelt>
  <servlet-name>NewService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>app.server.NewServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servelt>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>NewService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyApp/NewService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, when I add these lines and try to run my app I get a service unavailable error for one of my other servlets. I am certain the class path is right and that the class is being complied. Also I added these in between the web-app tag in the web.xml. Does anyone know why adding this servlet breaks my app?

---

**Edit:**

When I start my app on my computer I get this error:

> ```
> WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@6a360482{/,C:\Users\Admin\MyApp\war}
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: NewService
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1026)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1110)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:306)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
>     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:197)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:241)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
> ```

Comment: No, we don't. Without any context, startup log info, etc. we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like by specifying one servlet mapping, you are stranding the rest.  I think your web.xml should look something like this:

```
    ... etc ...
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/url1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.Servlet2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/url2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ... etc ...
```

How many other servlets do you have, and which one(s) are failing?  E.g., Only one right before the new one, only one after, all before, all after, or nothing so obvious?

**EDIT:**

Looking at your error messages, it's clear that the runtime is having trouble with your new servlet.  I think I see the problem.

You posted:

```
<servelt>
  <servlet-name>NewService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>app.server.NewServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servelt>
```

Change `servelt` to `servlet` and see if it helps.

Comment: I have 5 other servlets and the one to fail is the first one. I also updated my question with an error I get when I try to launch the app.

Comment: I feel really dumb right now. I was sure that I had double checked everything. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Funny thing is that the title of the post has the same typo :)